# Render result seems partially flipped on miyoo mini

Tags: c, sdl, game-engine, handheld

I'm trying to port game Freedink https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=freedink to Miyoo mini handheld. At the first run I saw this

1. [Splash screen is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5h36.jpg)
2. [In da house: stats is ok but homies are flipped.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Tke.jpg)
3. [The house collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F87x.jpg)

After some investigations I assumed that the problem is in **SDL_BlitSurface** function. After I changed this code

```
      {
    /* Copy splash to the background buffer so that D-Mod can
       start an effect from it (e.g. Pilgrim Quest's burning
       splash screen effect) */

    SDL_BlitSurface(splash, NULL, GFX_lpDDSTwo, NULL);
    SDL_FreeSurface(splash);
      }

    /* Copy splash screen (again) to the screen during loading time */
    SDL_BlitSurface(GFX_lpDDSTwo, NULL, GFX_lpDDSBack, NULL);

    flip_it();
  }
```

to this:

```
      {
    /* Copy splash to the background buffer so that D-Mod can
       start an effect from it (e.g. Pilgrim Quest's burning
       splash screen effect) */

    SDL_BlitSurface(splash, NULL, GFX_lpDDSThird, NULL);        //First copy to GFX_lpDDSThird
    SDL_BlitSurface(GFX_lpDDSThird, NULL, GFX_lpDDSTwo, NULL);  //And only then to GFX_lpDDSTwo
    SDL_FreeSurface(splash);
      }

    /* Copy splash screen (again) to the screen during loading time */
    SDL_BlitSurface(GFX_lpDDSTwo, NULL, GFX_lpDDSBack, NULL);

    flip_it();
  }
```

splash screen also become flipped. My question is simple: is this behavior known and how to fix this?